# Iceberg Flink catalog factory cannot find org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink, classpath, apache-iceberg

I have a basic application that tries to write some data into an Iceberg table using Flink:

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
tenv.executeSql("CREATE CATALOG hive WITH ('type'='iceberg', 'catalog-type'='hive')");
```

```
flink run --detached --class org.example.App Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
        at org.apache.iceberg.flink.FlinkCatalogFactory.clusterHadoopConf(FlinkCatalogFactory.java:211)
        at org.apache.iceberg.flink.FlinkCatalogFactory.createCatalog(FlinkCatalogFactory.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createCatalog(FactoryUtil.java:406)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.createCatalog(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1356)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1111)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:701)
        at org.example.App.main(App.java:36)
```

Why can't it find `org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`?

1. My Hadoop classpath is set: `HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*'` and the JAR is there: `/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar`

It's also on my dependency list:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and shaded into my JAR and I see the .class file in the archive.

Finally, I successfully instantiate it in literally the previous line!